# What's the best way to re-enable PPAs/repos after an upgrade?

Tags: ppa, repository, software-sources

When I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04, what's the best way to re-enable my PPAs and added repositories?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to add them all back/re-enabled them individually by uncommenting the lines in the files in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory.

Though upgrade time is a good time to reevaluate if you need the PPA in the first place if you were just using one to get a newer version of a package.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a bash script that removes the leading hash character from all files in `sources.list.d` that were disabled during the upgrade.

The following code is for upgrading `raring` sources to `saucy`.

If you want to keep the suffix `# disabled on upgrade to ...`, use

```
for f in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list; do sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' $f; sudo sed -i 's/^# \(.*disabled on upgrade to.*\)/\1/g' $f;done
```

if you want to delete the suffix `# disabled on upgrade to ...`, use

```
for f in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list; do sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' $f; sudo sed -i 's/^# \(.*\) # disabled on upgrade to.*/\1/g' $f;done
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a python script that uses the Python APT API to find and enable such sources, while setting the release to the current release:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3

import aptsources.sourceslist as sl
import lsb_release

codename = lsb_release.get_distro_information()['CODENAME']
sources = sl.SourcesList()

for source in sources.list:
    if source.comment.lower().find("disabled on upgrade") >= 0:
        source.dist = codename
        source.set_enabled(True)
        print(source)
sources.save()
```

If you run it without `sudo`, it won't be able to save changes, but it will show which sources would be enabled. Run with `sudo` to save the changes.

Comment: Does this replace, for instance, '# deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu artful/' with '# deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic'? What would happen if you didn't do that (as the response ahead of your does)?

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown it does, and if you don't replace it, it might happen that dependencies can't be satisfied.

Comment: I found that the word "artful" (the 17.10 codename) had been replaced with "bionic" in some of the lines that were commented "disabled on upgrade ...", while others weren't. I just uncommented all the lines with that "disabled" comment and apt proceeded to work (although I had to reinstall gcc for some reason). And I use a lot of third-party repos -- 13 files in `sources.list.d`, and three alien ones in `sources.list`. Might this be something that Ubuntu takes care of automatically now?

Comment: @JeffreyBenjaminBrown Possibly, I haven't upgraded in recent times (fresh installs, usually), so dunno.

Comment: This seems to have broken my apt sources files for 19.10

Comment: @Dreamcat4 without knowing what your `sources.list` looks like, not much I can do.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a couple of scripts to both enable (re-enable) and disable PPAs, specially after an upgrade. Here they are:

**PPA re-enable script**

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
# PPA re-enable script
# Use: ppa-reenable source.list
# to reenable a PPA without its source line
# Use: ppa-reenable src source.list
# to reenable a PPA with its source line

mod=1
file="$1"
if [ $1 == "src" ]; then mod=""; file="$2"; fi;
sudo sed -i "${mod}s/^# \(.*\) \(disabled on upgrade.*\)\?/\1/" "$file"
```

**PPA disable script**

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
# PPA disable script
# Use: ppa-disable source.list
# to disable the PPA completely
# Use: ppa-disable src source.list
# to disable the source of the PPA only

file="${1}"
mod=""
# If its only needed to disable the source
if [ $1 = "src" ]; then mod="2"; file="${2}"; fi;

# If source line is disabled, don't comment it out
second="`sed -n 2p \"$file\"`"
second="${second:0:1}"
if ( [ $second == "#" ] && [ $mod != "2" ] ); then
    mod="1"
fi

sudo sed -i "${mod}s/^/# /" "$file"
```

The `sudo` is included so you can store this script in your home bin directory

Answer (score 1):

To check and automatically update the *source.list* file, I created a script using `curl` and `codename` as follows.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

CODENAME="$(lsb_release -cs)"

for file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list; 
   do
      APT_URL="$(cat $file | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_-]*' | sort | uniq)"
      CURRENT_CODES="$(cat $file | rev | awk '{NF=2}1' | rev | awk '{print $1;}')"
      LENGTH=${#APT_URL}
      [[ ${APT_URL:LENGTH-1:1} != */ ]] && APT_URL="$APT_URL/"; :
      NEW_APT_URL="${APT_URL}dists/${CODENAME}"
      echo -n "$NEW_APT_URL"
      STATUS=$(curl --head --location --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null ${NEW_APT_URL})
      if [[ $STATUS == 200 ]]; then
         echo -en "\e[93m OK\033[0m"
         for code in $CURRENT_CODES;
            do
               [[ $code != $CODENAME ]] && sudo sed -i "s/$code/$CODENAME/g" $file
         done;
         sudo sed -i 's/^# \(.*\) # disabled on upgrade to.*/\1/g' $file
         echo -e "\e[92m DONE\033[0m"
      else
         echo -e "\e[91m NOT FOUND\033[0m"
      fi
done;
```