# How do I change my repositories to saucy from raring after upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, repository, 13.10, release-management

During the Saucy update it said that it would disable some packages, and it did.

In Software & Updates under Other Software a lot of my repositories are either "disabled on upgrade to saucy" or end in raring.
IE:

```
Http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu
Distribution: raring
Componets: main
Comment: disabled on upgrade to saucy
```

Do I just change the distribution to saucy?
Do I have to do that to all of them?

Comment: I wrote a `sed` script that removes the hash character: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade/381643#381643

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a bash script that removes the leading hash character from all files in `sources.list.d` that were disabled during the upgrade. I also posted the same code in [What's the best way to re-enable ppa's/repos after an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade/381643#381643).

The following code is for upgrading `raring` sources to `saucy`.

If you want to keep the suffix `# disabled on upgrade to ...`, use

```
for f in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list; do sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' $f; sudo sed -i 's/^# \(.*disabled on upgrade to.*\)/\1/g' $f;done
```

if you want to delete the suffix `# disabled on upgrade to ...`, use

```
for f in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list; do sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' $f; sudo sed -i 's/^# \(.*\) # disabled on upgrade to.*/\1/g' $f;done
```

Comment: Can you re-post it here please? If that other question is removed your answer here will no longer be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer is a few commands. You do have to re-check which ones you want (probably sticking to the ones that are commented as "Disabled on upgrade to saucy.")

```
sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: That only applies to sources.list rather than all the ppas listed in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. The correct form is `sudo sed -i 's/raring/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`. However, not all PPAs are updated for saucy yet, so you may want to actually set these as raring to use them.