# No new release found for Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, kde, do-release-upgrade

I tried to upgrade ubuntu with `do-release-upgrade` command. It started downloading for hours and some errors occured at the end. I tried again another day ,it started downloading more files but no success .

Now it's not updating anymore and prompts this message : `No new release found`
but my ubuntu version is 13.04 : `Release: 13.04`

I installed KDE and Gnome shell on ubuntu and now I'm using KDE

Comment: Looks like it upgraded, but not completely. I think you installation now is broken. What version of KDE is shown in Dolphin's "About"?

Comment: KDE Platform Version 4.10.5

Comment: Open your `sources.list` file and replace `raring` with `saucy`. To do this automatically, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/361614/7064)

Answer (score 1):

you can try upgrading using

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

-d is for checking devel-release upgrade

Cheers