# Re-enable working PPA's after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ppa

when I upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 all my ppa's disabled. whats the best way to re-enable working ppa in trusty(14.04)? and i used y-ppa manager to re enable but y-ppa is not working in trusty.

Comment: y-ppa works fine for me. Try reinstalling it?

Comment: Trusty is not released yet. A lot of PPAs will catch up after the release --- you should check if they have trusty version already or not, easily done in the launchpad web ppa page.

Answer (score -1):

worst upgrade I have gone through (13.10 to 14.04) [i386 version].  Upgrade portion before reboot went fine.  After it restarted, it broke grub, wouldn't boot.  Had to go through the following steps to rebuild grub from a 13.10 LiveCD;  This was in VirtualBox 4.3.10 r93012 VM.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
update-grub
exit && sudo umount /mnt/dev && sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts && sudo umount /mnt/proc && sudo umount /mnt/sys && sudo umount /mnt
```

then had to re-enable PPA's  through "Software and Updates">Other Software and clamtk's ppa can't be found.

Comment: What the heck are you doing? All you command are un-related to PPA. PPA repos are located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Have a look at something like [What's the best way to re-enable ppa's/repos after an upgrade?
](http://askubuntu.com/q/111645/22343)