# apt-get equivalent to yum's --enablerepo

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

Is there an easy way to use a repository/PPA only when needed as we'd do in a RHEL based distro with yum's `--enablerepo`, `--disablerepo` flags .

For example

```
yum --enablerepo=epel install vlc
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=centdvd list available
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade

Comment: also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/143203/how-to-disable-a-particular-ppa

Comment: Quite a relevant question still. There are many use cases, including 1) Install a package but not have it automatically updated due to version dependencies, 2) install a package from a repo with conflicting packages which you _don't_ want on the next `upgrade`, etc.