# Automatically check ppas if they work with next Ubuntu release

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, scripts, ppa

Is there a way to run some sort of script to see if the currently installed ppas have been updated with the latest release of Ubuntu? For example I'm on 16.04 and when 17.04 comes out, is it possible to have something check if all my ppas have been updated to work with 17.04 before upgrading? 
I don't want to upgrade then find out I can't readd the ppas and they don't work. I know I can do it manually via Launchpad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a tool to update my PPA sources.list entries after upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/42895/is-there-a-tool-to-update-my-ppa-sources-list-entries-after-upgrading)

Comment: Not an exact duplicate by probably what you want - http://askubuntu.com/questions/42895/is-there-a-tool-to-update-my-ppa-sources-list-entries-after-upgrading

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade

Comment: Not quite. I know how to do that already. As I understand it, ppas have to be updated by the maintainers to support Ubuntu releases and apt won't let you add them to your system if they don't support the version you're running. If that's the case then I'd like to know of a way of checking if they are compatible with the latest release.

Comment: Go to the PPA page and look if there are packages for your release. Abd why that weird upgrade from 16.04 to 17.04. 17.04 is not an LTS.

Comment: That was just an example. Seems I have to do it manually.