# How to keep PPA's enabled during 18.10 to 19.04 Release Upgrade?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

During release upgrades, PPAs and 3rd Party Repositories are disabled:

- [What's the best way to re-enable PPAs/repos after an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade)

How can disabling of PPAs and 3rd Party Repositories be prevented when upgrading 18.10 to 19.04?

Answer (score 2):

This article:

- [Ubuntu Users Can Now Keep PPAs And Third Party Repositories Enabled When Upgrading To A Newer Ubuntu Version](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/01/ubuntu-users-can-now-keep-ppas-and.html)

... describes a new ground-breaking development for Ubuntu users:

> Brian Murray, Ubuntu Bugmaster, says this should solve many of the
>   issues people are encountering when trying to upgrade from one Ubuntu
>   release to another. I'd also add that his makes it easier to continue
>   receiving updates to software installed from PPA / third-party sources
>   after an Ubuntu upgrade, while also not removing software that might
>   be otherwise removed due to incompatibility when upgrading.

You can use (in 18.10 now, in 18.04 soon) a new flag:

```
RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1 update-manager -d
```

**Note:** Only PPAs supported in the new version will be enabled:

> It's worth noting that you may still see a warning about third party
>   sources being disabled on upgrade, but those that support the Ubuntu
>   version to which you're upgrading will not be disabled.