# Ubuntu 22.04, how can I activate the old ppa from ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: upgrade

Yesterday I upgraded ubuntu (xubuntu) from the old version 20.04 to 22.04. During installation a message said that all ppa were inactivated. After installation I would like to reactivate them. I get a time out, when I choose "other Programs" "add" and then type in the field a address like: "ppa:opencpn/opencpn".

What can I do to get the updates for opencpn or keepass or vivaldi for example?

Thanks
Ronald

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to re-enable PPAs/repos after an upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade)

Answer (score -1):

Although it's an old thread, with respect to re-enabling old PPA's, do the instructions that are marked with a green checkmark [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111645/whats-the-best-way-to-re-enable-ppas-repos-after-an-upgrade) help? If you would like to access the sources list using a file manager as root, try using the following command in a terminal: `pkexec nautilus`

You may need to install "pkexec" and "gedit," as well, if they're not already installed.

https://installati.one/ubuntu/22.04/pkexec/

If that command don't work, you can try the instructions for 18.04 (the "GVfs method" mentioned in the first post) [here,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156998/how-do-i-start-nautilus-as-root) although I'm not sure they will work for 22.04.

Hope this helps! Please let us know how it turns out. :-)

Regards...

Comment: You're right, it's so close that it's actually a duplicate..

Comment: We posted the same link, I believe!! :-D

Comment: Yes, that was the intention. 

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I did not read the old issues because I am not an expert and I do not really know what to search. I do not understand that this feature is still an issue to UBUNTU. UBUNTU is able to deacitvate my ppa and after installing the upgrade UBUNTU is not willing to set my ppa active again. Now I have to ask stupid questions, sorry!

Comment: You're welcome, Ronald, I'm glad our answers helped! You didn't ask a stupid question at all, your issue would have stumped a lot of folks, including myself, I'm sure. Please let us know if you were able to fix this issue and if so, please post (an answer, not a comment) how you did it so others can learn, too! :-)